# How do i sort my list of tuples in ascending order e.g. my_list = [(6,4), (3,4)] to produce (3,4) (4,6)

Tags: python, function, sorting, tuples

How can i sort the below list of tuples to produce tuples of (3,4) (4,6)

```
my_list = [(6,4), (3,4)]
```

I have tried the following

```
items= [(3,4),(6,4)]
sorted_items= sorted(items)
print(sorted_items)
```

and

```
my_list = [(6,4), (3,4)]
my_list.sort(key=lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[1]), reverse=False)
print(my_list)
```

Thanks

Comment: So you want to sort not only the overall list of tuples, but also each tuple itself?

Comment: It seems like you want to sort the tuples, then the list of tuples. SO maybe something like: `sorted([tuple(sorted(t)) for t in my_list])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two calls to `sorted()` to generate the desired output:

```py
sorted(tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in my_list)
```

This outputs:

```py
[(3, 4), (4, 6)]
```